# Entity Framework 5 Cyclic Lazy Loading Cause OutOfMemoryException

Tags: lazy-loading, json.net, entity-framework-5, automapper

I have problem with EF 5 and Lazy loading with cyclic references.

The below picture represents my model. 
[image]

The main problem is between Model and ModelProperties classes, because Model contains IEnumerable navigation property and ModelProperty contains Model navigation property.

So this design cause the situation below
[image]

You can access fullsize image http://tinypic.com/r/2vskuxl/6

As you can imagine this cause very big problem, OutOfMemory exception.

Only solution that i could find is disabling lazy loading and using other methods. But lazy loading is very simplifying our work.
I hope there is a configuration or an attribute to help me loading only two levels of relations with lazy loading.

Is there any way to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**
Regarding the request from Julie Lerman, here is the visual model of EF.
I highlighted the main relation that cause problem.
[image] 
Also you can access full-size at http://tinypic.com/r/30v15pg/6

**UPDATE 2:**
Here is the model definitions.

```
public class Model {
        public int ModelID { get; set; }
        public int BrandID {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
        public string Logo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ModelProperty> ModelProperties {
            get;
            set;
        }
}

public class ModelProperty {

    public int ModelPropertyID {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual int PropertyDefinitionID {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual PropertyDefinition PropertyDefinition {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual int ModelID {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Model Model {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool IsContainable {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool HasFilterDefinition {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ModelPropertyValue> ModelPropertyValues {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ModelPropertyMatchingFilter> ModelPropertyMatchingFilter {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Also there is an entity configuration for ModelProperty.

```
 public class ModelPropertyEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ModelProperty> {
        public ModelPropertyEntityTypeConfiguration() {
            HasKey(p => p.ModelPropertyID);

            HasRequired(p => p.PropertyDefinition).WithMany(s => s.ModelProperties).HasForeignKey(s => s.PropertyDefinitionID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            HasRequired(p => p.Model).WithMany(s => s.ModelProperties).HasForeignKey(s => s.ModelID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            HasMany(p => p.ModelPropertyValues).WithRequired(s => s.ModelProperty).HasForeignKey(s => s.ModelPropertyID).WillCascadeOnDelete(true); 
            HasMany(p => p.ModelPropertyMatchingFilter).WithRequired(s => s.ContainerModelProperty).HasForeignKey(s => s.ContainerModelPropertyID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            ToTable("dbo.ModelProperties");
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 3:**
I am not sure but Automapper can cause this also. Because Entity Framework Profile tells thousands of Autommaper methods called while running.

**UPDATE 4:**
Here is the EFProf stacktrace:
[image]
You access bigger version http://tinypic.com/r/21cazv4/6

**UPDATE 5**
You can see sample project here: https://github.com/bahadirarslan/AutomapperCircularReference
In sample, you can see easily endless loops via Quick watch.

Comment: Bahadir, I am guessing that you are using code first so don't have an EDMX to look at. Can you use the EF Power Tool to generate a visual representation of your model and share it here? If you don't know how to use that tool, I demo it at about 19:00 in this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Entity-Framework-Tips-and-Tricks#time=19m00s

Comment: Can you show a piece of code that causes an `OutOfMemoryException`? In quickview you can drill down eternally, but then you trigger lazy loading yourself. What code or process in your application causes problems?

Comment: @JulieLerman i added the visual model of EF. I hope this helps.

Comment: @gert-arnold problem caused when i try to query ModelProperty table. There isn't any spesific code to achieve this. Only i am calling DbSet.ToList() in DbContext. This cause to query tremendous data from db because circular references and lazy loading

Comment: There must be _something_ that triggers lazy loading. Is there any code inside of the navigation properties `Model` and `ModelProperties`, or are they just simple get/set properties?

Comment: @GertArnold i just updated and added model codes. I know this will cause lazy loading but i hope there is an attribute that tells EF to stop second deepth level and stop triggering lazy loading.

Comment: Circular reference with lazy loading doesn't cause this issue. Dependencies are loaded only once unless there is something really wrong with your code (use sql profiler to see how many queries are really executed) - what you see in debugger are still same objects - that's why it is called circular **reference**. You may get some exceptions if you try to serialize those circular references.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to tell EF stop loading navigation properties more then predefined level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the update. You're model looks fine. It definitely knows this is just a 1:* relationship. Ladislav (as usual) is correct. LL doesn't cause the problem...except in ONE place which is during serialization. Is there a chance that you have your code in a service? With regular lazy loading, only the property you explicitly mention will get lazy loaded. But during serialization, the serialization "mentions" every property so it just keeps loading and loading properties throughout the graph AND causes circular dependency issues. With services we have to turn lazy loading off (using context.configuration.lazyloadingenabled=false) before you return the data. So in the service method, you can eager load, or lazy load or explicitly load to get your graph but then disable lazy loading before you return the results.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is very interesting, i thought different. I have  seperated tiers, EF is at DbCore and there is Generic Repository and UoW pattern. Over these layers, there Domain Service class and at the top there is Web API method. So where can i disable lazy loading?

Comment: I tried lots of things but stil couldn't find best solution. Also eager loading behaves very interesting than i thought.

Comment: can you use something like Entity Framework profiler and identify exactly what is triggering the lazy loading?

Comment: I profiled with EFProf and got lots of Select N+1 alerts. http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf/learn/alert/SelectNPlusOneInTheSameRequest . I couldn't understand isn't there any setting or attribute or configuration to tell EF or serializer do not fetch more than 2-3 level.

Comment: Also i couldn't understand your last sentences. "So in the service method, you can eager load, or lazy load or explicitly load to get your graph but then disable lazy loading before you return the results." what did you mention with service?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear with my question. EFProf it tells you what line of .NET code is causing a query to be executed. Can you see that? That is what I'm interested in. (We've already established that there is a serious problem in the database so yeah...I expect those N+1 warnings. :) )  And wrt service,  DataContract serialization WILL cause this problem. That's typically in a WCF Service. Is your EF code in a WCF service?

Comment: Regarding to EFProf Automapper calls cause this problems. I am calling Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source) and everything get crazy :) If i remove Automapper this time JSON Serializer cause this crazy LL problem. I started to believe there is no way to move this relation to upper layers. I am using ASP.NET Web Api.

Comment: oh you have added a note about automapper and I see now that you have tagged this post with automapper also. That could be your culprit. I've not used it with Entity Framework so I can't say. Is it possible to take it out of the loop temporarily to test? Now I suppose I'll go do some searching on automapper and EF to see if there are similar reports.

Comment: Yes i am updating question when i find a new clue or suspect :) I can take it out but this time JSON.Net Serializers cause very big problems like Automapper. As you said in your answer they are digging into deep until they reach OutOfMemory exception :) Something must stop this behavior.

Comment: so if automapper or json serializer is causing the problem then we are back to my suggestion about the service where the serializer can cause problelsm with lazy loading. Disable lazy loading (lazyloadingenabled=false) or the dynamic proxy (proxycreationenabled=false) at least in the problem methods and execute the load yourself either with eager or explicit loading. I know you want to use lazy loading but you can't control how far the serializer will go.

Comment: After disabling LL everything becomes normal. Because all navigation properties become null. I think i have to requery objects that i need at MVC layer via API again when they needed. Am i right? If i can't control depth level, waiving from LL is only option.

Comment: If Ladislav is correct, then serialization shouldn't make things go belly up, because re-reading a property would simply return the already fetched entity. Cyclic references could cause a serializer to go into an infinite loop if it is not very clever. Most are though. If profiling gives SELECT N+1's a lot, check where they are originating, i.e. the stacktrace. That will tell you where the culprit is. Otherwise it's just guesswork. Btw, JSON.NET can be told to test for cyclic references and obey them. Check its config params.

Comment: @FransBouma Ladislav seems correct. But i couldn't find a way to stop serializer or automapper in loop.

Answer (score 1):

you should disable lazy loading in order to bypass proxy objects or you should return what you need as a DTO. using DTO is preferred because of hiding details of your domain

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually i am using DTO and returning them from API after converting with Automapper. But i need these relations at upper layers, too. But not all of them, one or two levels ok for me.